# circular animation with fixed back ground image css

Tags: css

I have a circular animation with back ground image in css :

```
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #4897D8; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  background: url("../img/ExchangeHall.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

in this class the background image also rotating with the animation.

 how can i fix the background image ? just the border rotate and the background image must be fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write two classes and split the styles into both. Put one div inside the another and apply the styles

```
.loader-background {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #4897D8; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url("../img/ExchangeHall.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.loader-animation {
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


<div class="loader-background">
    <div class="loader-animation">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```